# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement with parameterized query

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm writing a desktop software with .NET and MS Access, but when I created the code to insert the data, it throws an exception and I've tried searching everywhere but still no fixes.

Here are all my columns (ignore the different language):

```
NomorNota (AutoNumber, PrimaryKey), Tanggal (Date/Time),
NamaPelanggan (Long Text), Alamat (Long Text), NoHP(Long Text),
TipeHP (Long Text), Keluhan (Long Text), Kerusakan (Long Text),
KondisiHP (Long Text), Kelengkapan (Long Text), Warna (Long Text),
KataSandi/Pola (Number), DP (Currency), Teknisi (Long Text), Status (Long Text), 
TanggalKonfirmasi (Date/Time), IsiKonfirmasi (Long Text),
Biaya (Currency), TambahanBiaya (Currency), TotalBiaya (Currency),
HargaSparepart (Currency), Laba/Rugi (Currency)
```

And here's my c# code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                Data Source=Databases/database.accdb;
                Persist Security Info=False";

    try
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        conn.Open();

        string kelengkapan = "";
        string status = "";

        int totalBiaya = int.Parse(txtBiaya.Text) + int.Parse(txtTambahanBiaya.Text);
        int labaRugi = totalBiaya - int.Parse(txtHargaSparepart.Text);

        if (chckSIM.Checked)
            kelengkapan += "SIM ";

        if (chckMemory.Checked)
            kelengkapan += "Memory ";

        if (chckKondom.Checked)
            kelengkapan += "Kondom ";

        if (chckBaterai.Checked)
            kelengkapan += "Baterai";

        if (comboStatus.SelectedItem != null)
            status = comboStatus.SelectedItem.ToString();
        else
            status = "BELUM DISETTING";

        string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO DataServisan (Tanggal, NamaPelanggan, Alamat,
                    NoHP, TipeHP, Keluhan,
                    Kerusakan, KondisiHP, Kelengkapan,
                    Warna, KataSandi/Pola, DP,
                    Teknisi, Status, TanggalKonfirmasi,
                    IsiKonfirmasi, Biaya, TambahanBiaya,
                    TotalBiaya, HargaSparepart, Laba/Rugi) 
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        cmd.CommandText = cmdText;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtNamaPelanggan.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtAlamat.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtNoHP.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtTipeHP.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtKeluhan.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtKerusakan.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtKondisiHP.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = kelengkapan });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtWarna.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = int.Parse(txtKataSandiPola.Text) });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = int.Parse(txtDP.Text) });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtTeknisi.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = status });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = dateKonfirmasi.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtIsiKonfirmasi.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = int.Parse(txtBiaya.Text) });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = int.Parse(txtTambahanBiaya.Text) });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = totalBiaya });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = txtHargaSparepart.Text });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = labaRugi });

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Berhasil!", "Transaksi Servis");

        this.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: i'm getting System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the columns that have a slash in them, so in your insert statement, change:

- `KataSandi/Pola` to `[KataSandi/Pola]`
- `Laba/Rugi` to `[Laba/Rugi]`

You generally should avoid such characters in column names. It makes your code harder to read. When reading your mind may first think it is a division, only then to realize it is a column name.

Without explicit quoting, the parser has the same problem, except it throws a syntax error instead of realizing it was a column name after all.

Comment: +1 thx i changed the name so that it has no slashes in them and set in the code so that the datagridview has slashes in them.